# Java security and encyryption APIs - Invalid entry password to recover secret.Given final block not properly padded

Tags: java, security, encryption

I m creating a keystore file using Java API i.e an equivalent to java command

```
keytool -genseckey -alias some.alias -keyalg AES -keysize 128 -keypass <an encrypted byte string>  -storetype JCEKS -keystore  <filename> –storepass <some_pwd>
```

code :
...

```
key=get128MD5(strToHash);
        System.out.println(String.format("Hashing value : '%s' ", Hex.toHexString(key)));
         
        try {   
         KeyStore.ProtectionParameter protParam =
                    new KeyStore.PasswordProtection("XXXXX".toCharArray ());

         javax.crypto.SecretKey mySecretKey=new SecretKeySpec(key,"AES");

        KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry skEntry =
            new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(mySecretKey);
            ks.setEntry(alias, skEntry, protParam);
            
            try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("filename")) {
                ks.store(fos, "XXXXX".toCharArray ());
                fos.close();   
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (KeyStoreException e1) {
...

above error happens when trying to load from keystore file :

public static Key getKey(String keyalias,byte[] keypassbyte) throws KeyStoreException {
        Key key = null;
        try{            
            if(ks!=null){
                log.info("Getting key from Keystore.");
                key =ks.getKey(keyalias, Hex.toHexString(keypassbyte).toCharArray());               
            }
            
            if(key==null){
                throw new KeyStoreException("Failed to get secret key entry.");
            }
        }catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae) {
            throw new KeyStoreException("Algorithm for recovering the secret key cannot be found." + nsae.getMessage());
     `   }catch (UnrecoverableEntryException uee) {
            throw new KeyStoreException("Invalid entry password to recover secret." + uee.getMessage());
        }catch (KeyStoreException kse) {
            throw new KeyStoreException("Failed to get secret key entry." + kse.getMessage());
        }catch(NullPointerException ex){
            throw new NullPointerException("NullPointerException " + ex.getMessage());
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get secret key."+ e.getMessage());
        }
        return key;
```

Any idea where things go wrong ? I tried different varainats of the "ks.setKey method and including length parameer which did not help. I m using WIN10 and Eclipse/Java 1.8

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
key =ks.getKey(keyalias, 
Hex.toHexString(keypassbyte).toCharArray())
```

Trying to use a hex form of the password? Why? Just use same as when the key  is created